# RavenDB Spatial Index - Child Property

Tags: ravendb, spatial

I've got a spatial index and search working in a prototype and now I'm trying to integrate it into our proper solution that has a slightly different data model and it's not coming back with any search results.

These are my classes

```
public class SpatialDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public SpatialDataShapeModel SpatialDataShape { get; set; }
}

public class SpatialDataShapeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }      
    public DbGeography Shape { get; set; }
}
```

I've defined the index a couple of ways:

```
public class SpatialDatasIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<SpatialDataModel>
{
    public SpatialDatasIndex()
    {
        Map = points => from p in points
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            __ = SpatialGenerate("Coords", p.SpatialDataShape.Shape.Latitude, p.SpatialDataShape.Shape.Longitude)
                        };
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SpatialDatasIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<SpatialDataModel>
{
    public SpatialDatasIndex()
    {
        Map = points => from p in points
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            __ = SpatialGenerate("Coords", p.SpatialDataShape.Shape.AsText())
                        };

        Spatial(x=>x.SpatialDataShape.Shape, o=>o.Geography.Default());
    }
}
```

Here i'm using the type DbGeography and and trying to get out the WKT

and I'm trying to query like this:

```
using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    data = session.Query<SpatialDataModel, SpatialDatasIndex>()
        .Customize(x => x.WithinRadiusOf(
            fieldName: "Coords",
            radius: 1,
            latitude: query.Lat,
            longitude: query.Lng))
        .Take(query.PageSize)
        .ToList();
}
```

Any help getting this working would be great, I can't find much documentation and the bits on the Raven site I've read many times.

**UPDATE**

JSON

```
{
  "Title": "Test 1",  
  "SpatialDataShape": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Shape": {
      "Geography": {
        "CoordinateSystemId": 4326,
        "WellKnownText": "POINT (-0.1217937469482422 51.51461834694225)"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: What does your document looks like? Please show the JSON

Comment: Have updated... any ideas?